# Keycloak 'resourceAccess' error after importing BrowserAnimationsModule in app module

Tags: angular, angular-material, keycloak

I am new to Angular and `keycloak` getting this error after importing `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` into app module:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: An error happened during access validation. Details:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resourceAccess')
Error: An error happened during access validation. Details:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resourceAccess')
    at keycloak-angular.mjs:33:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:375:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:24260:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:374:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at zone.js:1278:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1168:17)
    at zone.js:1281:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:409:31)
    at core.mjs:23946:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23946:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24247:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:408:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
```

I can't understand why this error appears and how can `BrowserAnimationsModule` be related to this

This is my app module code:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BusinesTripComponent,
    TasklistComponent,
    BusinesFormComponent,
    ClickOutsideDirective

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DialogModule,
    CommonModule,
    BusinesTripRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TableModule,
    ToolbarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    FormsModule,
    InputTextModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('keycloakInfoService', keycloakInfoReducer),
  ],
  entryComponents: [TasklistComponent],
  providers: [
    TaskListService,
    BusinesTripService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }

  ]
})
export class BusinesTripModule { }
```

Authguard.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected override readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService,
    protected store: Store
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    // Force the user to log in if currently unauthenticated.
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
      });
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

Also this error appears only if i import `BrowserAnimationsModule` into child application, importing it into parent application doesn't lead to any errors.